# How to copy distinct values from one stack to another

Tags: c#

I have two Integer stacks **StackA** and  **StackB**.

**StackA** has the following values but **StackB** has no content.

```
StackA
-----
[40]
[11]
[56]
[10]
[11]
[56]
```

Now i need to copy distinct values from **StackA** to **StackB**.I tried this

```
    public static void CopyDistinctValues(Stack<int> source, Stack<int> destination)
    {
        int[] numArray = source.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!destination.Contains(numArray[i]))
            {
                destination.Push(numArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

and its working but i am not sure if its the best solution.

*Is there a better way to do this or any built in method to achieve this?*

It will be better if it can be done without using Array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way would be:

```
stackB = new Stack<int>(stackA.Distinct().Reverse());
```

Reverse is required because constructor takes `IEnumerable` and Stack's implementation of `IEnumerable` makes it to start from the last item.

Comment: but your code works inline not in the CopyDistiinctValues method call

Comment: I want to point out that Distinct is a set operation and as such the results are unordered (see the remark under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct). So it's not guaranteed that the new stack has them in the right order. Depending on how Distinct is implemented it may be ordered though, but this implementation detail may change in later .NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use Linq in this case like

```
Stack<int> stacka = new Stack<int>(new[] { 40, 11, 56, 10, 11, 56 });
Stack<int> stackb = new Stack<int>(stacka.ToArray().Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            Stack<int> StackA= new Stack<int>();
            StackA.Push(2);
            StackA.Push(3);
            StackA.Push(4);
            StackA.Push(5);
            StackA.Push(2);
            Stack<int> StackB = new Stack<int>();
            StackB = new Stack<int>(StackA.Distinct());
```